# Can not import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode

Tags: java, spring, rest, thymeleaf

I'm following the below tutorial which is based on sending an email using Thymeleaf template.

link to the tutorial:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

In this example TemplateMode is being used in several instances

```
 private ITemplateResolver textTemplateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(1));
    templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("text/*"));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
    templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

While I was searching for it I found it is in org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode but I cant import it to my project

So TemplateMode gives me errors. How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [`org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templatemode/TemplateMode.html) was added in Thymeleaf 3.0.0.

As long as you depend on a version of Thymeleaf >= 3.0.0 then `TemplateMode` will be available to you so the fact that `TemplateMode` is not available on your project's classapth **strongly** implies that you are using a version of Thymeleaf < 3.0.0.

The bottom line is that the [example](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) you linked to uses Thymeleaf >= `3.0.0` whereas you are using Thymeleaf < `3.0.0`.

FWIW, your question also tags `spring` so perhaps you are acquiring your Thymeleaf dependency transitively (via `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` perhaps?). You could run `mvn dependency:tree` and review the output for: `org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf` to understand (a) what version of Thymeleaf you are using and (b) where this version comes from.

Comment: I have checked my pom.xml. This is what I found.
 <thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>1.3</thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>
 <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>1.4.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
 <thymeleaf.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

Comment: I set the version to 3.0.11 but it still not able to resolve imports.what would be the case?