# org.thymeleaf.templatemode.StandardTemplateModeHandlers can't be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring boot API, I need to send an email using Thymeleaf.Therefore, I chose [this](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Sending-Mail-Template-From-Spring-Boot-Application-Using-Thymeleaf/) tutorial.However, when adding **ThymeleafConfig.java**, STS throws the following error.

> The import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.StandardTemplateModeHandlers
>   cannot be resolved

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958686/8810941) answer, I changed the dependencies as follows.But it didn't solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**ThymeleafConfig.java**

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
//following import is not resolved
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.StandardTemplateModeHandlers;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;


@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

  @Bean
  public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver(){
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.HTML5.getTemplateModeName());
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return emailTemplateResolver;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use TemplateMode instead of StandardTemplateModeHandlers

```
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
```

In HTML template, use th:text

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <p th:text="${name}">
</body>
</html>
```

When you are processing your template , use thymeleaf's TemplateEngine

```
 import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine; 

   @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

       Context context = new Context();
            context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
            String html = templateEngine.process("email-template", context);
```